# List manipulation challenge

Tags: list-manipulation

It's necessary to get

[image: Out:]

from

[image: In:]

```
list = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3},{a4, b4, c4}, {a5, b5, c5}};
```

I'd like to do this with `ReplaceList`. Is it feasible? Or, maybe, you know a better way?

Comment: If you do it only once, just write it directly as you want: it will be the simplest. If you will apply it to many lists of the same structure, try `ReplacePart `.

Comment: Don't post pictures in lieu of actual code/lists/etc. Why should a reader have to manually copy/type?

Comment: Shouldn't the first element in your resulting list be `{a1, b1, c2/a1}`?

Comment: No, it's `{a1,b1,c2/c1}`

Comment: @vudum I have posted an approach which, though not having the form of your answer, does replicate the desired manipulations of list (with Mathematica rearrangements)

Answer (score 6):

Written for brevity:

```
list = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}, {a4, b4, c4}, {a5, b5, c5}};

f[x_][n_] := {Tr@#, Sqrt@Tr[#2^2], x[[3, n + 1]] Tr@# / #.#3} & @@ x[[All, ;; n]]

f[list\[Transpose]] ~Array~ 4
```

> ```
> {{a1, Sqrt[b1^2], c2/c1},
>  {a1 + a2, Sqrt[b1^2 + b2^2], ((a1 + a2) c3)/(
>   a1 c1 + a2 c2)},
>  {a1 + a2 + a3, Sqrt[b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2], ((a1 + a2 + a3) c4)/(
>   a1 c1 + a2 c2 + a3 c3)},
>  {a1 + a2 + a3 + a4, Sqrt[b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2 + b4^2],
>     ((a1 + a2 + a3 + a4) c5)/(a1 c1 + a2 c2 + a3 c3 + a4 c4)}}
> ```

`Sqrt[b1^2]` remains in the output rather than `b1` but I think this is reasonable.

Comment: Shortest so far, I like it. +1

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks!

Comment: You could add a performance test for all answers :-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang Mine will not fare well due to the repetitive sums so I'll leave performance testing for someone who took a different emphasis.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1 much neater and I like the way dealt with indexing...as usual I learn a lot :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and I realize I could exploited transpose at beginning rather than messier parts...live and learn...

Answer (score 5):

As ciao comments code facilitates answers rather than pictures. As the base list is small I post the following. There will almost certainly be better ways and I have not simplified `Sqrt`:

```
 dat = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}, {a4, b4, c4}, {a5, b5, c5}}
 func[u_] := FoldList[Append, {u[[1]]}, u[[2 ;; -2]]]
 col1 = Accumulate[Most@dat[[All, 1]]];
 col2 = Sqrt[#.#] & /@ func[dat[[All, 2]]];
 col3 =
   MapThread[
    #1/#2 &,
    {Rest@dat[[All, 3]],
     MapThread[
      #1.#2/Plus @@ #2 &,
      {func[dat[[All, 3]]], func[dat[[All, 1]]]}]}
    ];     
 Transpose[{col1, col2, col3}]
```

this yields:

```
(*{{a1, Sqrt[b1^2], c2/c1}, {a1 + a2, Sqrt[
  b1^2 + b2^2], ((a1 + a2) c3)/(a1 c1 + a2 c2)}, {a1 + a2 + a3, Sqrt[
  b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2], ((a1 + a2 + a3) c4)/(
  a1 c1 + a2 c2 + a3 c3)}, {a1 + a2 + a3 + a4, Sqrt[
  b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2 + b4^2], ((a1 + a2 + a3 + a4) c5)/(
  a1 c1 + a2 c2 + a3 c3 + a4 c4)}}*)
```

Comment: That's not the OP example... :-| I'll venture the picture has pictypos...second term has Sqrt[b1^2+b1^2] there. But +1 for putting up with it !

Comment: @ciao I am sorry if I have misunderstood...my cursory view suggested this  was the same just with just some rearrangement...if the form was required I guess I did not do that...just thought posting something would either help or clarify...:-/

Answer (score 3):

Not very efficient, but this brute force approach has the advantage of being very easy to code.

```
data = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}, {a4, b4, c4}, {a5, b5, c5}};
{aa, bb, cc} = Transpose @ data;
as = Most @ Accumulate[aa];
bs = Most @ Sqrt @ Accumulate[bb^2];
cs = 
  Table[
    Module[{as = aa[[;; i]], cs = cc[[;; i]]}, cc[[i + 1]] Total[as]/(as.cs)], 
    {i, Length @ cc - 1}]
result = Transpose @ {as, bs, cs}
```

> ```
> {{a1, Sqrt[b1^2], c2/c1}, 
>  {a1 + a2, Sqrt[b1^2 + b2^2], ((a1 + a2)*c3)/(a1*c1 + a2*c2)}, 
>  {a1 + a2 + a3, Sqrt[b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2], 
>     ((a1 + a2 + a3)*c4)/(a1*c1 + a2*c2 + a3*c3)}, 
>  {a1 + a2 + a3 + a4, Sqrt[b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2 + b4^2], 
>     ((a1 + a2 + a3 + a4)*c5)/(a1*c1 + a2*c2 + a3*c3 + a4*c4)}}
> ```

Comment: FYI: `Sqrt[b1 + b2 + b3]` should be `Sqrt[b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2]` etc.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks for pointing out my error. I've repaired my code

Answer (score 2):

My take (but the fractions in the third element are always converted from `a/(b/c)` to `ac/b`, such is life).

```
transform = 
 {Total@#1[[1 ;; -2, 1]],
  Sqrt[Total@(#1[[1 ;; -2, 2]]^2)], 
  #1[[-1, 3]]/((#1[[1 ;; -2, 1]]).(#1[[1 ;; -2, 3]])/Total@#1[[1 ;; -2, 1]])
 } & 

transform[list[[1;;#]]]&/@Range[2,Length@list]
```

Alternatively, because `First`, `Rest`, `Most`, and `Last` are better than `Part`:

```
transform = 
  {Total@(First /@ Most@#),
   Sqrt[Total@(Most@#^2)][[2]], 
   Last@Last@#/((First /@ Most@#).(Last /@ Most@#)/Total@(First /@ Most@#))
  } &
```

Comment: I see that your method is quite similar to my own, so +1 for you too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you too. Cleaned the code up a bit as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
l[n_, x_] := Transpose[list[[;; n]]][[x]]
{Tr@l[#, 1], Norm@l[#, 2], Last@l[# + 1, -1]/l[#, 1].l[#, 3]  Tr@l[#, 1]} & /@ Range@4
```

Comment: `Abs` was not called for.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Neither `Sqrt[b1^2]`:)

Comment: I suppose, but I think my change is the logical result whereas this is a different operation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, the word "logical" has a few meanings. [**Here is a nice one**](http://www.thenation.com/article/killing-commons/) I was reading right now.

Comment: +1 for your cheeky answer as well as the interesting article you sidetracked me with.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Glad you liked Noam's article. He's a master using the Ockham's razor

Answer (score 1):

And here's a different enough approach to merit a separate answer.

```
ListCorrelate[
  {1, 1}, 
  Accumulate@list,
  {1, -1}, {}, #2 &
  {#[[1]], Sqrt@Total@({Sequence @@ #1[[2]]}^2), 
   #2[[-1, -1]] #[[1]]/{Sequence @@ #[[1]]}.{Sequence @@ Last@#}} &, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before programming, you should analyse the construction of the ***formula***.

For the first column, you could construct the following list

```
{{a1}, 
 {a1, a2}, 
 {a1, a2, a3}, 
 {a1, a2, a3, a4}}
```

For the second column

```
{{b1}, 
 {b1, b2}, 
 {b1, b2, b3}, 
 {b1, b2, b3, b4}}
```

For the last column, constructing the list as follow

```
{{{a1}, {c1}}, 
 {{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}}, 
 {{a1, a2, a3}, {c1, c2, c3}},
 {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}}}

{c2, c3, c4, c5}
```

**Implementation**

```
data = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}, {a4, b4, c4}, {a5, b5, c5}}
{lstA, lstB, lstC} = Transpose@data;
len = Length@data;
```

Then

```
col1 = Plus @@@ (lstA[[1 ;; #]] & /@ Range[len - 1])
(*col1 = Accumulate[Most@lstA]*)
col2 = Sqrt[#.#] & /@ (lstB[[1 ;; #]] & /@ Range[len - 1])
col3 = 
  (Plus @@ #1/#1.#2 &) @@@ ({lstA[[1 ;; #]], lstC[[1 ;; #]]} & /@
   Range[len - 1]) lstC[[2 ;;]]
```

Lastly, you can transpose the three columns.

```
Transpose[{col1, col2, col3}]
```